# Convert Join Result to Two Column with SQL

Tags: sql, unpivot

I have a JOIN Result as following

```
Address1 Address2 Address3
ABC       XYZ      LMN
```

I want to convert them to following format

```
Address    Level

ABC         1
XYZ         2
LMN         3
```

Comment: @NasmiSabeer It is actually `UNPIVOT` not `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to `UNPIVOT` or `UNION ALL`. These take your columns and converts it into rows. A `UNION ALL` can be done on all RDBMS:

```
select address1 Address, 1 as level
from yourtable
union all
select address2 Address, 2 as level
from yourtable
union all
select address3 Address, 3 as level
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6cb6/1)

If you are using an RDBMS with the `UNPIVOT` function (SQL Server 2005+/Oracle 11g+) then your query will be similar to this:

```
select Address, 
  right(Level, 1) Level
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  address
  for level in (Address1, Address2, Address3)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d933c/2)

The result for both is:

```
| ADDRESS | LEVEL |
-------------------
|     ABC |     1 |
|     XYZ |     2 |
|     LMN |     3 |
```